# Coerce superclass to subclass

Tags: r, coercion, reference-class

I have a class, `D`, that contains a virtual class, `A`. I would like to coerce the pieces of `D` that comprise `A` into one of two subclasses for `A`. Is this possible with R's reference classes?

The desired output is to have a new object of class `D` that inherits either `B` or `C`, both of which are subclasses of `A`. My motivation is to have the fields of `B` or `C` accessible at the top level. I am trying to avoid storing the superclass `A` in one of the fields of `D` which is the obvious workaround.

```
## Toy classes
A <- setRefClass("A", fields=c(f1="numeric", f2="numeric"), contains="VIRTUAL")

## B and C are subclass of A
B <- setRefClass("B", fields=c(b_field="numeric"), contains="A")
C <- setRefClass("C", fields=c(c_field="numeric"), contains="A")


## D is a subclass of A as well, but can take either a B or a C
D <- setRefClass("D", fields=c(d_field="numeric"), contains = "A")

setAs("A", "B", def = function(from) {
  # ??? what goes here?
})


d <- D$new()
result <- as(d, "B")
```

Result should have the fields unique to class `D`, all of the fields from class `A`, and the field from class `B`.

Comment: This is not my understanding about coercion. I believe `as(new("D"), "B")` should contain only the fields of B.  Why not to inherit D from both B and C?`D <- setRefClass("D", fields=c(d_field="numeric"), contains = c("B","C"))` ?

Comment: In my real use case, the D class can only contain one of B or C. They are subclasses of A that override A's methods. Think of A as an interface. B and C are two different implementations of the interface with the same method names.

Comment: My hope was that R would recognize that D inherits from A and then coerce only the A pieces to B. This is likely not possible.

Comment: How the contrary can be possible? If you coerce D to B , the result should be a B class that contain only B fields...

Comment: Because I didn't implement a coerce method for D to B. Only A to B. Is there a way to say, "D contains B (which contains A)" and still is an object of class D?

Comment: I don't see other solution than storing A a s a field of D.